# Unable to add AppCompat library to project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and I've both **"Android Support Library"** and **"Android Support Repository**" installed. I also have Android **4.4**, **4.3** and **4.1.2** installed.

What I did so far: `File > Import > Add existing Android code` > ... > `Appcompat`
That worked, it's now in my *package explorer*. When I try to add the library to my project, nothing happens. In fact, when I check back in *properties > Library* it has a "**red cross**". (it had a green icon when I added it at first).

[image]

Comment: Is the directory where you have AppCompat writeable?

Comment: Yeah it is, it's a folder in my Documents

Comment: Generally I import also the library in eclipse. I verify that the google api level of library = my project google api level , this you see in android properties , it is top where you see the library , after importing it , you should be able to set it .

Comment: I have Android 4.4 selected in properties, it does nothing when I click apply once I added the library.
So he doesn't even find the import "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;"

Comment: Did you select "copy to workspace" when you imported the library? Maybe you have one copy of the library in your workspace from before and now you are referencing the copy you have in "My Documents" and that might be creating a confusion? If you have a copy of the library on your workspace, delete it. The next time you import it do not select "copy to workspace". See if that work, it is a long shot but...

Comment: There is no copy in my workspace :(

Comment: Okay, it worked now. I added the .jar file manually to my library. Thanks for your help all